# Неправильно работает запрос на MySQL 5.6 и выше

Tags: mysql, sql

Данный запрос почему-то возвращает "Empty set" на mysql 5.6 и выше.
На mysql 5.5 запрос прекрасно работает и выдает список из одного столбца product_id. Помогите переделать, пожалуйста. Или что в этом запросе не так? Что изменилось в 5.6?
Тип таблиц: InnoDB

```
SELECT `product_id` 
FROM `characteristic_value_product` 
WHERE `characteristic_value_id` IN ('22') 
GROUP BY `product_id` 
HAVING COUNT(1) IN (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                    FROM (SELECT distinct characteristic_id 
                          FROM characteristic_values 
                          WHERE id IN ('22')
                         ) char_val
                   );
```

Comment: И дело скорее всего в `HAVING COUNT(1)`, но не знаю как пофиксить

Comment: Забавный запрос... самый внутренний подзапрос отдаёт `characteristic_id` с `id=22`. Средний - считает их количество. Внешний соответственно выбирает те `product_id`, которые имеют столько же характеристик (если что-то в структуре обеспечивает уникальность, то это имеет смысл, иначе вообще бред)... соответственно: 1) Добавьте везде алиасы таблиц; 2) Замените `IN` во внешнем запросе на равенство; 3) Сверните подзапросы в один, считайте сразу `COUNT(DISTINCT characteristic_id)`.

Comment: Не стоит искать какой-то особенный смысл в этом запросе, так как это маленькая часть другого запроса. Я скинул лишь кусок в котором есть проблема. Алиасы добавил, а заменять `IN` на равенство не вижу смысла, так как предусмотрено не только одно значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, отвечу сам на свой вопрос. Все гораздо проще, чем я думал. Уже рабочий запрос имеет данный вид:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM characteristic_value_product 
WHERE characteristic_value_id IN ('22') 
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1 IN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT characteristic_id) 
                          FROM characteristic_values 
                          WHERE id IN ('22')
                   );
```

Дело исключительно в `HAVING COUNT(1) = 1`. *Алиасы, как подсказали в комментариях для ответа убрал, чтобы было минимум отличий*

Comment: Тут вообще какая то ерунда написана. Если такая конструкция работает то она означает примерно следующее "если подзапрос вернул в том числе запись со значением 1 то вернуть записи внешнего запроса, для которых count(1) дает 1. во всех остальных случаях не возвращать ничего". Вы бы задачу описали, что именно должен получить этот запрос, его наверняка можно выразить гораздо проще